# Salesforce SOSQL Combine 3 Objects

Tags: subquery, salesforce, relationship

Can you combine 2 child objects to a parent object?

```
SELECT SourceIp FROM LoginHistory WHERE UserId IN (SELECT Id FROM User) 
SELECT City FROM LoginGeo WHERE CreatedbyId (SELECT Id from User)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
SELECT SourceIp,
    UserId,
    LoginGeo.City
FROM LoginHistory
ORDER BY UserId
```

You can read up about the [`LoginHistory`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_loginhistory.htm) object, there are some sample queries too.
Other than the documentation if you want to explore relations (what can/can't be queried "up" via lookup or "down" via related list) you'd need something that shows you metadata info. Eclipse? Salesforce Workbench?

There are some [ERDs available for standard objects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/api/data_model.htm) but I don't see anything useful to you...

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to combine 2 child objects, which are, LoginHistory and LoginGeo in this case to UserObject. I am aware you cannot arbitrarily join queries.

Comment: Sometimes you can query parent (User) + related lists. But in this scenario if "describe" call doesn't return relationship name it won't work. I'm talking about something like `SELECT Name, (SELECT Id FROM Contacts), (SELECT Id FROM Cases) FROM Account`

Comment: Tries this in SQL Editor and it returns 'Didn't understand relationship 'LoginGeo' in FROM part of query call. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names'. The describe call doesn't return any relationship.

Comment: What's this "SQL editor"? How ancient the tool is? That documentation link says that "LoginGeo" is visible in API v 34 and above, that's since about 2.5 years ago. I'm sure my query works in Developer Console -> Query editor and in http://workbench.developerforce.com/. Maybe you need to force your tool to log in with higher API version (but then I don't get it how you'd be able to make your old query against LoginGeo table...)

Comment: I meant Query Editor. The first query that you posted works in QE and in workbench. If you try using the second query with LoginGeo,LoginHistory objects it returns 'Didn't understand relationship 'LoginGeo' error in QE

Comment: You may have to user 2 different queries. The only reason I wanted User object was to retrieve FirstName and LastName.

Comment: Try `SELECT SourceIp,
    UserId,
    LoginGeo.City, LoginGeo.CreatedBy.Name
FROM LoginHistory
ORDER BY UserId` although I don't like it, check results carefully. I'd feel better about it if I could go "up" from Login History rather than login geo.